# com.ycuwq.widgets/datepicker not available in maven repository

Tags: android, datepicker, jcenter, maven-repository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ycuwq.widgets/datepicker says 1.3.1 available in jcenter.

But jcenter is not available at https://jcenter.bintray.com/. How to find the repository which could have a copy of this library

Answer (score 0):

I try with this one but no issue appear.

```
implementation("com.ycuwq.widgets:datepicker:1.3.1")

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I put dependencyResolutionManagement under allprojects { ..}, its failing right now to build